# Can a python dictionary use re.compile as a key?

Tags: python, regex, dictionary, hashtable

We have 10-20 dictionaries that follow this basic format, the key is the value to be assigned and the value is the regex:

```
osTypeRE = collections.OrderedDict([
    ('WINDOWS', re.compile('^.*(windows|WIN2008|WIN2003).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('LINUX/UNIX', re.compile('^.*(unix|linux|ubuntu|red hat|redhat|RHEL|CentOS|CENT OS|Debian|SLES|SUSE|freebsd|free bsd|AIX|Solaris|SunOS).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('MAC', re.compile('^.*(mac os x).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('STRATUS VOS', re.compile('^.*(VOS|Stratus).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('MAINFRAME', re.compile('^.*(OS400|AS400).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('CISCO IOS', re.compile('^.*(IOS).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('NETWARE/OES', re.compile('^.*(NETWARE|OES|Open Enterprise Server).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('OPENVMS', re.compile('^.*(VMS).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('HYPERVISOR', re.compile('^.*(ESX).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('HP NONSTOP', re.compile('^.*(NONSTOP|Tandem|NON STOP).*|.*(H06.20).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
    ('EMBEDDED', re.compile('^.*(QNX).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE))
])
```

These type of dictionaries have proven very useful as it allows us to standardize computer information from multiple management systems so that information can then be reconciled.

The only problem is that it is too slow. Here is the function we use to normalize our data using this type of dictionary:

```
def reg_lookup(lookup, re_dict):
    value = "INDETERMINATE"
    for key, reg_ex in  re_dict.items():
        matched = reg_ex.search(lookup)
        if matched:
            value = key.upper()
            break
    return value
```

So basically, we loop thru the dictionary values (which are regex) and when we find a match we take the key and that becomes the new standardized value.

But since we are looping thru the dictionary, we are losing the speed associated with the dictionary type hash table. But how would we overcome this? Can I simply swap the key and value pairs in these dictionaries? But then how would my reg_lookup function need to change and would it be faster?

Another example dictionary:

```
osVerRE = collections.OrderedDict([
    ('WINDOWS', collections.OrderedDict([
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2000 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2000).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2003 ENTERPRISE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER|.* SR )(?=.*2003)(?=.*ENTERPRISE|.* Ent).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2003 STANDARD', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2003)(?=.*STANDARD|.*STD).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2003 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2003).*|(?=.*WIN2003).*|(?=.*Windows)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2k3).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2008 ENTERPRISE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2008)(?=.*ENTERPRISE|.* ENT).*|(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2K8)(?=.*ENTERPRISE|.* ENT).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2008 STANDARD', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2008)(?=.*STANDARD|.*STD).*|(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2K8)(?=.*STANDARD|.*STD).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2008 DATACENTER', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2008)(?=.*DATACENTER).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2008 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2008).*|(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2K8).*|(?=.*WIN2008).*|(?=.*WINDOWS 2K8 R2).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2012 DATACENTER', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2012)(?=.*DATACENTER).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2012 STANDARD', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2012)(?=.*STANDARD).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2012 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2012).*|(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*2012 R2).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS NT 4.0', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*NT)(?=.*4\.0).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS XP PROFESSIONAL', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*XP)(?=.*PROFESSIONAL).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 10 PROFESSIONAL', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*10)(?=.*PRO).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 7 ENTERPRISE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*7)(?=.*ENTERPRISE).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 7 PROFESSIONAL', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*7)(?=.*PROFESSIONAL).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*7)(?=.*ULTIMATE).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER LINE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS XP LINE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*XP).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 7 LINE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*7).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 8 LINE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*8).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS 10 LINE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*10).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE))
    ])),
.
.
.
```

Comment: Well, if you have to loop you have to loop... Why use a dictionary in the first place?

Comment: If you need to check each expression for a match anyway, what difference does it make?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: you do not have to loop since a lexer does these tasks as well and works in the length of the content to parse, not the amount of potential tokens.

Comment: You do not have a mapping issue. You still need to test all your regexes to see which one matches.

Comment: Side note: instead of `value = key.upper()` and then `break` and then `return value`, you can just do `return key.upper()`.

Comment: juana: I somewhat agree... the dictionary just makes it a little more readable than a bunch of if statements in a loop, but that's about it. Tiger: That's why I'm wondering if there is another way... rather than looping.

Comment: @user3656612: yes there is: you could use the same way a lexer is constructed. Right now I'm at work, but if I find some time I might take a look at it. It is described in detail in *Appel*'s book on compilers.

Comment: Well, if you are going to loop, loop over a list of tuples.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: in fact you don't. A lexer - the first step in a compiler - uses dynamic programming to lex the file of a program. It analyzes concurrently whether the token will be a string literal, identifier, integer, floating point, etc. With some preprocessing, this is done in a way the *number* of tokens a programming language defines, has no impact on performance.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: you generally use one or only very few regexes for that, to extract a token type. The OP here isn't lexing however.

Comment: @user3656612: you could just use a list of tuples. You don't have a mapping here, you have a *pairing*. That's not the same thing, you never use one of the elements of the pairing to quickly find the other.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: yes but the point is that even if you defined a million regexes with a lot of overlap, if you do preprocessing, it will tokenize in *O(n)* with *n* the length of the string. It uses a labeled DFA in the background, so the number of regexes has no impact.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: Where do you see overlap in the regexes here? I'd like to focus on *this question*, not on other types of problems. This is not such a problem.

Comment: Why do all your regexes use `^.*` and `.*$`? Those are redundant, as are the `re.MULTILINE` flags. You only need to find if a specific word is present (or one of a set of words).

Comment: There is some overlap in other dictionaries, there are 10-20 dictionaries for processing computer asset information, standardizing across different logging servers, IDS/IPS systems, and management databases. Total reconciled records (computers) is about 250,000. Because of the overlap, I switched to ordered dictionaries so that a president is set.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: well here `OPENVMS` and `STRATUS VOS` both start with a `V` as regex, what I mean is that while you eat the stream of tokens, it is in the beginning undecided which type of token you are parsing. With overlap I mean there is a *substring* that is part of both regexes. Say you write a parser that takes ints and floats, if the text is `10.14` as long as the decimal dot is not eaten, the DFA will say both are still possible. It thus labels the states of the DFA with the type of tokens.

Comment: Martin: some look like this '^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2000).*$', so I suspect I included it in this dictionary for consistency and readability sake, even though redundant. I'm not a regex master at the moment, rusty.

Comment: Why are you using an `OrderedDict` (additional overhead vs. a dictionary) in the first place? You can easily get by with a list of 2-tuple pairings.

Comment: The ordering proved necessary for certain dictionaries. For example, "('SUSE 9.4', re.compile('^(?=.*SUSE)(?=.*9\.4).*|(?=.*SLES)(?=.*9\.4).*|(?=.*SLES)(?=.*9-4).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE))," needed to be checked and matched before "('SUSE 9 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*SUSE)(?=.*9).*|(?=.*SLES)(?=.*9).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE))," so that information is not lost in the standarization.

Comment: Is speed important? Doing all these regexes is redundant - you're looping over the string a ton of times. This is 'nicer' but much slower than just string parsing. Do you really want to stick with these? The one word regexes can be replaced with a standard string search as well.

Comment: Check this library if you have to use regexes, the captures dict and one long regex with '|' should do the trick (followed by a bunch of 'ifs') : https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex

Comment: Honestly, I probably would've written it different... I probably would use a loop for each field, instead of a dictionary for each field, and a bunch of if x in y type statements to produce normalized values for each field. But... politics has come into play. My bosses boss thinks regex is the way to go, my boss doesn't want to challenge him on it, so me a lonely contractor cannot either. Ultimately, the dictionary solution is a little neater... it is a little easier to tweak and tune than a bunch of if statements would be. But that is why... if I find something much better, I can suggest it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping through a dictionary with the desired result as the key and each possible result's expression as a value, why not do one regex search (since your expressions are very basic) and then look up the result in a dictionary?

```
def reg_lookup(lookup, expression=re.compile('windows|WIN2008|WIN2003|unix|linux|ubuntu|red hat|redhat|RHEL|CentOS|CENT OS|Debian|SLES|SUSE|freebsd|free bsd|AIX|Solaris|SunOS|mac os x|VOS|Stratus|OS400|AS400|IOS|NETWARE|OES|Open Enterprise Server|VMS|ESX|NONSTOP|Tandem|NON STOP|H06.20|QNX', re.MULTILINE|re.IGNORECASE), dct={'windows':'WINDOWS', 'WIN2008':'WINDOWS', 'WIN2003':'WINDOWS', 'unix':'LINUX/UNIX', 'linux':'LINUX/UNIX'}):
    result = expression.search(lookup)
    if result:
        return dct[result.group()]
    else:
        return 'INDETERMINATE'
```

Note that `H06.20` matches any character for the `.`. If you want a literal dot, use `H06\.20`.

Comment: You should also bitwise-or the flags argument - `re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE` instead of `re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE`

Comment: Good answer, the only thing is that the regex becomes completely unnecessary with this approach. i.e. for all 250k computer assets, I could just create a dictionary with every observed variation as the key and the standardized value as the value. This would take full advantage of the hash table speed, but I fear it would not be as flexible and dynamic in nature. Thanks for the . correction.

Comment: Could you explain why the bitwise or is better please?

Comment: @user3656612 - How "flexible and dynamic" does it have to be? Do you intend to use expressions that actually take advantage of regex features, or will they always be predetermined strings? If the full `lookup` is always one of several predefined strings, it should just be `dct.get(lookup, 'INDETERMINATE')` in the first place, for O(1) runtime.

Comment: You might be right, to get the speed do away with regex and just lookup the values. But you have to consider the nature of the data; i.e. the dictionaries would be huge. e.g. Take just the WINDOWS line, this will match everything with the word windows, win2008 or win2003 in it. But, if I just made the actual unstandarized values  the keys, it would fail on windows 2003 sp1, for example.... but... now I see that's where your regex solution would come into play. hmm...

Comment: Maybe there is a better, from scratch, solution to this problem. Basically, we have 4-5 different systems we are grabbing this data from (for 250k computer assets). None of the data is normalized/standardized. My job is to first normalize it and then reconcile it to produce a single list. We have many other fields and dictionaries such as device type, mfr, model, country, etc... some systems use USA for the country, others use a country code 1. So, the idea is that as long as we normalize the data sources using the same dicts, or equal, data across all systems will be easier to reconcile.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I am using, at least for now. It takes advantage of the speed of the hashing table for items that were previously matched using the dictionary lookups and forms the faster dictionary during lookups for new items.

I am experiencing a 50% to 75% speed increase, depending on the datasource being standardized. Its a little convoluted, but not a bad solution... seems to provide the best of both worlds. Thoughts?

```
fast_lookup = {"mfr":{}, "model":{}, "dev_type":{}, "os_type":{}, "os_ver":{}, "country":{}, "state":{}, }

def reg_lookup(lookup, re_dict, dict_name):
    global fast_lookup
    try:
        #First try the faster dynamically generated dictionary
        return fast_lookup[dict_name][lookup]
    except:
        #Otherwise, use the lookup dictionaries
        for key, reg_ex in  re_dict.items():
            matched = reg_ex.search(lookup)
            if matched:
                #Should a match be found, add it to the faster dictionary
                fast_lookup[dict_name][lookup] = key.upper()
                return key.upper()
        return "INDETERMINATE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are some pretty horrific regexes. It looks like they all boil down to a handful of fixed strings, some with options and required combinations, none with order. My first reaction was to wrap them in `(?P<name>...)` sections and join them into a giant regex, after which you could request the groupdict; given there are no capturing groups inside (let alone named ones), you could even use lastgroup (but you'd want the order of the tests reversed, and it wouldn't shortcut). But that will make the code even uglier. I would prefer an approach where the substrings aren't wrapped in `^.*(?=.*...).*$`, but simply listed; there's too much noise as it is.

Here's a crude conversion method to extract the strings themselves and produce some matchable sets:

```
import re, itertools

l=[('WINDOWS SERVER 2000 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2000).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2003 ENTERPRISE', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER|.* SR )(?=.*2003)(?=.*ENTERPRISE|.* Ent).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2003 STANDARD', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2003)(?=.*STANDARD|.*STD).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),
        ('WINDOWS SERVER 2003 SERIES', re.compile('^(?=.*WINDOWS)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2003).*|(?=.*WIN2003).*|(?=.*Windows)(?=.*SERVER)(?=.*2k3).*$', re.MULTILINE+re.IGNORECASE)),]

def re2wordsets(e):
    # Extracts the words, and converts alternatives into multiple sets.
    groups=map(str.lower,re.findall(r'\(\?=\.\*([^)]*)\)', e.pattern))
    groups=[g.split('|.*') for g in groups]
    for words in itertools.product(*groups):
         yield set(words)

# Convert to set form
l2 = [(k,list(re2wordsets(e))) for (k,e) in l]
# Collect all words that are used
allwords = reduce(set.union, itertools.chain(*(i[1] for i in l2)))
# Build a search regex to find any of them
allwordsre = re.compile('|'.join(allwords), re.IGNORECASE | re.MULTILINE)

# Use that regex once to find all relevant words in some string
foundwords = set(map(str.lower, allwordsre.findall(somestring)))
# Then see if we find a matching set
# Note: this could be simplified if we flatten the list of sets
# e.g. [(k,v1), (k,v2)] instead of [(k,[v1,v2])]
for k,vs in l2:
    for v in vs:
        if v.issubset(foundwords):
            print k
            break
    else:     # none of our sets matched, check next entry
        continue
    break
```

By the way, the answer to the titular question is yes in CPython 2.7.10, re pattern objects (SRE_Pattern) are hashable and can be used as keys, though that may be implementation dependent as it isn't explicitly specified in the documentation. Though I'm not sure that really applies for the problem.

Comment: The main reason for the question is to speed things up. i.e. the way it is now, I have to loop thru the dictionary values and do regex compares one by one. Takes about 50 seconds for 150,000 records and I'd like something faster. so I was thinking of reversing the key and value... but don't really know how that would work.